# Changing elements in an array based on another array in loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

It's a dice game. Each player rolls the dice two times (I defined a function to do this) and I save the dice rolls in an array. So a turn with three players could look like `[[1,6], [3,4], [5,2]]`.

I want to create an array that saves the score (the sum of the two dice rolls) of each player. I want `score[0] == Player 1`, `score[1] == Player 2`, etc.

I tried creating an empty array with length equaling the number of players, and then changing the elements of the array while in a loop.

```
def dice(players):
    score = [0]*players 
    rolls = [] 
    for i in range(0,players):
        rolls.append(diceroll(2))
        for r in rolls:
            score[i] += sum(r)
    return rolls, score
```

For dice(6), I got this:

```
([[1, 2], [2, 2], [4, 2], [6, 2], [6, 4], [1, 1]], [3, 7, 13, 21, 31, 33])
```

instead of this, which I wanted:

```
([[1, 2], [2, 2], [4, 2], [6, 2], [6, 4], [1, 1]], [3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2])
```

Why does the score section of it add to the previous index? Can someone explain? I want it to just add to `score[i]`, and keep the players separated.

Edit: I want to be able to do multiple turns of dice, so that the score can increase. That's why I don't want to do `score[i] = sum(r)`

Comment: You're doing cumulative sum instead of score 'per-palyer'. In other words, rolls keeps account of all rolls (for previous players as well), and when you do `sum(r)` it adds together the previous dice rolls too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're for loops are nested and that is your issue. Ill try to explain.

Here's your code.

```
def dice(players):
    score = [0]*players 
    rolls = [] 
    for i in range(0,players):
        rolls.append(diceroll(2))
        for r in rolls:
            score[i] += sum(r)
    return rolls, score
```

Basically you've asked python to run a for loop so that every player gets to roll once and you append that roll to `rolls`.
But also every player after their roll you asked python to then calculate all rolls that have currently happened each time a player rolls. So player 1 roll get calculated multiple times.

This code should work for you. Look at the location of the for loops, also notice i removed `+=` to `=` since we don't need to add to the score we just need to calculate the score then store it.

```
def dice(players):
    score = [0]*players 
    rolls = [] 
    for i in range(0,players):
        rolls.append(diceroll(2))

    for i in range(len(rolls)):
        score[i] = sum(rolls[i])
    return rolls, score
```

Now we did each player rolls once and once everyone has rolled we then have another for loop outside that calculates the scores.

Comment: In the last loop, `i` is always equal to `players - 1`

Comment: That shouldn't affect the code. It will still work unless there is something I'm missing from you posted code.

Comment: Ohh i see what you mean, that is my bad typo. Please look at the edit.

Comment: Well OP wants "an array that saves the score of _each_ player", while that last loop only works with the _last_ player

Comment: Thanks for that catch. I spaced on changing it from foreach to a for.

Comment: I tried what you said but changed it to `for r in range(0,len(rolls)`. Then it worked, I think. I got `([[3, 6], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 2], [2, 5], [2, 6]], [9, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8])` so thanks!

Comment: Oh my gosh sorry I'm just having a brain fart of a day today. You're you do need to put it into a range. Well I'm glad my broken code helped. Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the score section of it add to the previous index?

This loop says that `score[i]` is the sum of all values in the `rolls` that have been generated so far:

```
for r in rolls:
    score[i] += sum(r)
```

So it's calculated like this:

```
score[0] = rolls[0][0] + rolls[0][1]
score[1] = (rolls[0][0] + rolls[0][1]) + (rolls[1][0] + rolls[1][1])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the previous roll
score[2] = (rolls[0][0] + rolls[0][1]) + (rolls[1][0] + rolls[1][1]) + (rolls[2][0] + rolls[2][1])
           ^^^roll prior to the previous ^^^^^^^^^ the previous roll
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your problem into smaller parts.

You have a list in which each object contains the dice rolls by a single player.

```
for playerRolls in players:
```

Now `playerRolls` is a list containing the numbers that each player rolled. The sum of these is their score. So

```
    playerScore = 0
    for diceRoll in playerRolls:
        playerScore += diceRoll
    # or a nicer way:
    playerScore = sum(playerRolls)
```

Now append this value to score

```
    score.append(playerScore)
```

All together:

```
score = []
for playerRolls in players:
    playerScore = sum(playerRolls)
    score.append(playerScore)
```